# Seaborn subplot x axis is not displaying properly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I created subplots using seaborn but my x-axis are not displaying correctly. The years are out of order? why is this?

Here is my code and output:

```
g=sns.relplot(x="Year", y="Indicator_Value",
           data=Emissions_R_df,
           kind="line",
           style="Indicator_Name",
           hue="Indicator_Name",
           row="Country_Name"
           )
g.fig.suptitle("Amount of Emissions from CO2, CH4, N20, and others - 1960-2014", y=1.05)
g.set(xlabel="Years",
     ylabel="Emissions, kiloton(kt)")
g.fig.set_size_inches(15,20)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(steps=[10]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: try `Emissions_R_df['Year'] = Emissions_R_df['Year'].astype(int)` before all of your code.